# Django HttpResponseRedirect doesn't work in form_valid

Tags: django

I have a custom button in an admin `changelist` template that opens a jQuery dialog containing a form inside an `iframe`. After submission, the dialog closes and I want to redirect to the same admin `changelist` page. I have something like this:

```
class UploadSeqDataQcView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'fantoddcc/frmUploadSeqDataQc.html'
    form_class = UploadSeqDataQcForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('admin:myapp_seqdata_changelist'

    # ...

    def form_valid(self, form):

        # A 'success' message must appear after submission is processed successfully:

        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'The QC parameters were successfully imported.')

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

The problem is that the `HttResponseRedirect` seems to do nothing. After submission, I cannot see the `successful`message. However, if I press 'F5' to refresh the page on the browser the message appears.

I would appreciate any hint.

Comment: Since this called from within an iframe, the response is only seen by the iframe itself. You'll have to handle the redirection at the js level

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I was thinking the same and very likely you are right. But, I've tried to add the `window.location.reload(true)` in the function that closes the dialog in the js script that is loaded by the customized `change_list.html` template but the effect is the same. I was wondering if it is possible to forward the response to the parent window from Django.

Comment: "it is possible to forward the response to the parent window from Django" => Definitely not. No way. Not a chance. Django doesn't know zilch about your browser - he gets a request, returns a response and that's it, period.

Comment: Also do you really need an iframe at all ?